# How to delete from table that has many different relationships and delete the item and all related?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a product that has 6 relationships as follow:

- brand->belongsTo(Brand::class);
- tags->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tags_product');
- fields->belongsToMany(Field::class, 'product_field');
- sizes->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'product_size');
- countries->belongsToMany(Country::class, 'country_product');
- countryProducts->hasMany(CountryProduct::class);
- productFields->hasMany(ProductField::class);
- exportationFactors->hasMany(ExportationFactor::class);

Do I have to get rid of those relations first or not necessarily?

Currently I have this code for the delete function

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$products = $request->all();

try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $dbProduct = $this->getProduct($product['SKU']);
        $dbProduct->brand()->delete();
        $dbProduct->tags()->delete();
        $dbProduct->fields()->delete();
        $dbProduct->sizes()->delete();
        $dbProduct->countries()->delete();
        $dbProduct->exportationFactors()->delete();

        Log::error($dbProduct);
        $dbProduct->delete();
    }

    DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
    throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error eliminando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
}
```

And I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sondel`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_brand_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `brands` where `brands`.`id` = 2)

Comment: You have to delete the rows in the other table that are linked to this table BEFORE you can delete the parent row. OR set up a CONSTRAINT to cascade deletes

Comment: @RiggsFolly how would I delete the rows first?

Comment: I think its presumed that you would either a) know or b) have access to the database's schema so you would use that information to see in which tables foreign keys are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I arrived to:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        $products = $request->all();
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product = $this->getProduct($product['SKU']);
                $product->sizes()->detach();
                $product->tags()->detach();
                $product->fields()->detach();
                $product->countries()->detach();
                $product->exportationFactors()->delete();
                $product->delete();
                DB::commit();
            }

            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error eliminando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
        }
```

and in vue.js

```
sendData(data, index) {
                this.loading = true;
                this.error = {};
                this.$http.post(this.baseUrl, data, this.params)
                    .then(
                        () => {
                            this.successAction();
                            this.statuses[index] = 1;
                            this.errorDis = false;

                        },
                        (res) => {
                            this.showErrors(res);
                            this.statuses[index] = 2;
                            this.errorDis = true;
                        }
                    );
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dbProduct->delete();
Brand::where('product_id', $dbProduct->id)->delete();
Tags::where('product_id', $dbProduct->id)->delete();
```

and add all the tables